# Trying to deploy an ASP.NET web application to azure from BitBucket and getting error

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am trying to deploy an asp.net web app from BitBucket to an Azure web app and getting the below error:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment with MSBuild.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\Sertech\project.json...
Committing restore...
Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write. Path: D:\home\site\repository\src\Sertech\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\src\Sertech\Sertech.xproj
Restore completed in 1753ms.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1SertechWebApp\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  Cannot find DNX runtime dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 in the folder: .dnx\runtimes
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(248,5): error MSB4044: The "GetBuildOptions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RuntimeToolingDirectory". [D:\home\site\repository\src\Sertech\Sertech.xproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Sertech.sln" /nologo /verbosity:m /p:deployOnBuild=True;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release;UseSharedCompilation=false;publishUrl="D:\local\Temp\8d3d203fca67f23"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\57.50831.2397\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

The Publish Web option in Visual Studio works just fine, the issue only happens from a BitBucket deployment.

What I've tried so far in no particular order:

- Use custom deployment script I found while searching the issue.
- Use custom deployment script downloaded from the Kudu page of my
  Azure web app.
- Change the SDK version in VS.
- Install the dnx-clr-win-x86 nuget package locally.
- Install the dnx-clr-win-x86 nuget package on the web app resource
  using the Azure console (this failed to find a package).

If anybody can point me in the right direction for troubleshooting further or has a solution I would be very thankful.

Comment: Try this one. https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/2207

Comment: The issue is only happening on the Azure side, the build works fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNX? RC1? A release candidate isn't quite RELEASED software. Just as *The Donald* isn't the president just because he's a candidate (well at least not as of this writing).

**ASP.NET 5.0 betas**, **Core 1.0 RC1** and **Core 1.0 RC2** are no longer supported in Azure App Service.

Admittedly this was announced in a blog post so visibility may suffer - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/06/14/supporting-asp-net-5-core-rc1-on-azure-app-service/

> **Is ASP.NET 5, Core RC1, RC2 supported on Azure App Service?**
>
> No, ASP.NET 5, Core RC1 or RC2 is no longer supported on Azure App Service. The only supported ASP.NET Core stack is RTM on Azure App Service. Check the newly announced RTM version at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/06/27/azure-app-service-and-asp-net-core/

No wonder you see things breaking. Upgrade your project to ASP.NET Core 1.0 **RTM** and redeploy.

Official migration guide here:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html

Comment: ASP.NET compatibility ended up being the issue. I had to update Web Tools to the latest version to get ASP.NET Core Web Application to show up in my VS and create a new project, but the new project deployed with no errors. Thanks so much!